# How to output data as HTML from JSON object using getJSON

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json, setinterval

Hello there I will try and keep this simple and short

I have a getJSON function that runs every 5 seconds. Now when I display the data using document.write function it dosent seem to want to update. The page is stuck in a loading loop. How can I get the data to display on my page? My JSON is fine but I will show you anyways.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

 $.ajaxSetup ({  
    cache: false  
     });  

    setInterval(function(){ $.getJSON('names.json', function(data) {

    for(i in data)  {

        document.write(data[i] + "<br/>");
    }

  });



},5000);

 </script>
```

This is the JSON object

```
{
  "one": "",
  "two": "Beady little eyes",
  "three": "Little birds pitch by my doorstep"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't actually use `document.write`.  Once the page is loaded, that will erase the page.  Use (jQuery's) DOM methods to manipulate the DOM.

```
$.getJSON('names.json', function(data){
    for(var i in data){
        $('#myDiv').append(data[i]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you use jQuery,

I used this to create a form from my json item, I hope this helps...

```
function jsonFormCreator(frmJSON)
{
    var createdHTML = ""; var elementType, id;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(frmJSON));



    for(item in frmJSON)
    {
        formElement = frmJSON[item];    elementType = formElement.elementType;  id = formElement.id;

        if(elementType == "input")
        {
            createdHTML += "<input id='" + id +"'";
            if(formElement.type == "checkbox") 
            {createdHTML += " type='" + formElement.type + "' checked='" + formElement.checked + "'";}
            else{createdHTML += "type='" + formElement.type + "' value='" + formElement.value + "' onclick='" + formElement.onclick + "'";}
            createdHTML += "/><br>"
        }
        else if(elementType == "textarea")
        {createdHTML += "<textarea id='" + formElement.id  + "' rows='" + formElement.rows +  "' cols='" + formElement.cols + "' value='" + formElement.value + "'></textarea><br>";}
        else if(elementType == "select")
        {
            var options = formElement.values;
            createdHTML += "<select id='" + formElement.id+ "'>";
                for(i = 0 ; i < options.length ; i++)
                {createdHTML += "<option value='" + options[i][0] + "'>" + options[i][1] + "</option>";} //Adding each option
            createdHTML+= "</select><br>";
        }
    }
    console.log("Complete");console.log(createdHTML);
    document.getElementById('mainContainer').innerHTML = createdHTML;//Adding to the DOM
}
```

And my JSON would look like this

```
{
    "0": {
        "elementType": "input",
        "id": "frm1",
        "type": "text",
        "value": "form Liam",
        "label": "Test Text Input"
    },
        "itemBTN": {
        "elementType": "input",
        "id": "frmAlert",
        "type": "button",
        "onclick" : "loader(homePage);",
        "value": "Home Page",
        "label": ""
    },
    "item2": {
        "elementType": "textarea",
        "id": "frm2",
        "rows": 5,
        "cols": 30,
        "value": "helddddddddlo",
        "label": "Test Textarea"
    },
    "item3": {
        "elementType": "select",
        "id": "frm3",
        "values": [
            [
                "value1",
                "Pick Me"
            ],
            [
                "value2",
                "UserDis2"
            ],
            [
                "value3",
                "UserDis3"
            ],
            [
                "value4",
                "UserDis4"
            ],
            [
                "value5",
                "UserDis5"
            ],
            [
                "value6",
                "UserDis6"
            ]
        ],
        "label": "Test Select"
    },
    "item4": {
        "elementType": "input",
        "id": "frm4",
        "label": "Checkbox",
        "type": "checkbox",
        "checked": true
    }
}
```

This code adds the form in to my div tag with the id mainContainer
I know its alot of code, but i hope it helps !

Answer (score 1):

You want to render dom which will contain the data, then when you get the data update the dom.

As an exceedingly simple example, on your page have a container

```
<div id="one"></div>
```

and then in your ajax success handler

```
$("#one").text(json.one);
```

This uses jquery to grab the dom element with id "one", and update its text.