# Displaying JSON attribute into JSP page

Tags: json, spring, jsp

I have table column named 'data' that contain JSON data type on my db. Said that my column 'data' contain this:

```
{"username":"jimmy"; "email":"jimmy@hotmail.com"; "gender":"male"; "age":18}
```

I want to display 'username' and 'age' attribute to my JSP page. Can someone show me how to do that?

> nb: Im using Spring Framework, and Im very new with this technology. Sorry if my question is not specific.

Comment: Kindly check - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11545562/how-to-output-data-as-html-from-json-object-using-getjson

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-hello-world-example/

Comment: @shashankmishra i think it answer for .json file , but in my case i want to select the attribute from my db column. Can suggest any other source?